# Flutter getting files from Firebase Storage

Tags: flutter

I'm developing application that user can post their photos, and I'm working with modify part. I get their images as `File` type first, store them in Firebase Storage and get download URL and store it in Firestore, and then show them with `Image.network()`, but in modify page I'm using `Imagecropper` which requires the path of image, so I have to convert it to `File` type, not `String`. Does anyone know how to get files from firebase, not downloadURL??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the downloadURL to download the file and save it on the device.

You can use this plugin: https://pub.dev/packages/image_downloader

If you don't want to use any plugin, have a look into this:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/59356482/11847608

Comment: But my purpose is not to download the image to the device, but to convert Image.network to Image.file

Comment: Without fetching/downloading the image file to the device, I don't think you will be able to do any kind of operation on it. You have to load it, then do your operation and once you are done, remove the file from the device.

Comment: Is it possible to delete images inside flutter?

Comment: You can delete files from directory, if you know the path. https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/dart/flutter+delete+file

Answer (score 0):

If you need to download a file you have stored in cloud storage you could use *writeToFile* method

> you can call the *writeToFile* method on any storage bucket reference. The location of where the file will be downloaded to is determined by the absolute path of the File instance provided,

here is the code from the Api doc

```
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';

Future<void> downloadFileExample() async {
  Directory appDocDir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
  File downloadToFile = File('${appDocDir.path}/download-logo.png');

  try {
    await firebase_storage.FirebaseStorage.instance
        .ref('uploads/logo.png')
        .writeToFile(downloadToFile);
  } on firebase_core.FirebaseException catch (e) {
    // e.g, e.code == 'canceled'
  }
}
```

Comment: What is getApplicationDecumnetsDirectory()'s role?

Comment: it gets a directory that only your app can use so you can store your files in it

Answer (score 0):

This is how I was able to solve this,

```
 String userImageUrl = "";
 File _imageFile;
uploadToStorage() async {
   
    String imageFileName = DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch.toString();

    StorageReference storageReference =
        FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child(imageFileName);

    StorageUploadTask storageUploadTask = storageReference.putFile(_imageFile);

    StorageTaskSnapshot taskSnapshot = await storageUploadTask.onComplete;

    await taskSnapshot.ref.getDownloadURL().then((urlImage) {
      userImageUrl = urlImage;

      print(userImageUrl)
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I did not find any pretty solution around here so I now decided to create me own handy function. Hope this helps someone :)

```
  Future<File> downloadToTmpFile({required String ref}) async {
    final dir = await getTemporaryDirectory();
    final filePath = "${dir.path}/${ref.split('/').last}";
    final file = File(filePath);

    final downloadTask = ref.storageRef.writeToFile(file);
    await downloadTask;
    return file;
  }
```

Note that i have written a String extension:

```
extension StringExtension on String {
  Reference get storageRef => FirebaseStorage.instance.ref(this);
}
```

Ensure that you still have to catch exceptions. Or if you want - you can further modify your the function by handling individual TaskSnapshots differently. This is only the minimum functionalety.