# How to get a Flutter Uint8List from a Network Image?

Tags: image, file, dart, flutter, byte

I'm trying to convert a network image into a file and the first part of that is to convert it into a Uint8List.  Here is how I'm doing this with 1 of my asset images...

```
      final ByteData bytes = await rootBundle.load('assests/logo');
      final Uint8List list = bytes.buffer.asUint8List();

      final tempDir = await getTemporaryDirectory();
      final file = await new File('${tempDir.path}/image.jpg').create();
      file.writeAsBytesSync(list);
```

How can I do this with `Image.network(imageUrl.com/image)`

Answer (score 27):

The simplest way seeems to get the http response using the image url and `response.bodyBytes` would contain the data in `Uint8List`.

```
http.Response response = await http.get(
    'https://flutter.io/images/flutter-mark-square-100.png',
);   
response.bodyBytes //Uint8List
```

Now you can do things like converting to base64 encoded string `base64.encode(response.bodyBytes);`
**Update**: With newer version of http, you need to add Uri.parse()
Eg.

```
http.Response response = await http.get(
    Uri.parse('https://flutter.io/images/flutter-mark-square-100.png'),
);
```

Comment: Using this method to get a File as File file = File.fromRawPath(uint8list); I get the following error : The following FileSystemException was thrown resolving an image codec:
Cannot open file, path = '.....'

Comment: The problem with this answer is that it downloads the file again regardless of it being in cache or not, causing users to wait and diminishing UX.

Answer (score 11):

I figured out a different solution. Hope it helps someone.

```
import 'dart:typed_data';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

Uint8List bytes = (await NetworkAssetBundle(Uri.parse(imageUrl))
            .load(imageUrl))
            .buffer
            .asUint8List();
```

Comment: Seems like not working for Flutter Web (3.0.5), error shows Unsupported operation: Platform._version. Same problem here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60435601/how-to-download-image-from-network-and-use-as-an-asset-image-offline-in-flutter

Answer (score 7):

```
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    var sunImage = new NetworkImage(
        "https://resources.ninghao.org/images/childhood-in-a-picture.jpg");
    sunImage.obtainKey(new ImageConfiguration()).then((val) {
      var load = sunImage.load(val);
      load.addListener((listener, err) async {
        setState(() => image = listener);
      });
    });
  }
```

See also https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/23761#issuecomment-434606683

Then you can use `image.toByteData().buffer.asUInt8List()`

See also https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/dart-ui/Image/toByteData.html

Comment: I'm revisiting your answer and now i'm getting an error on buffer that it isn't defined for ByteData when I use the following code...  `final Uint8List list = image.image.toByteData().buffer.asUInt8List();`.  Am I missing something?  Please help.

Comment: @CharlesJr image.image.toByteData() returns Future<ByteData>. `ByteData data = await mage.image.toByteData(); data.buffer.asUInt8List();`

Comment: I have error with sunImage.load(val). The error is 2  positional argument(s) expected, but 1 found. Can I know how to solve it?

Comment: Seems the API has changed. Check what the 2nd parameter id that the `load` function expects.

Comment: @syonip Some more details would be helpful. Any error message?

Comment: my obtainKey() returns _SizeAwareCacheKey, but bundle.load() expects String

Answer (score 2):

After trying for hours this is what helped me

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:path/path.dart' as path;
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';

Future<File> getFileFromNetworkImage(String imageUrl) async {
  var response = await http.get(imageUrl);
  final documentDirectory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
  String fileName = DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch.toString();
  File file = File(path.join(documentDirectory.path, '$fileName.png'));
  file.writeAsBytes(response.bodyBytes);
  return file;
}

final file = await getFileFromNetworkImage("<your network image Url here>");
```

Note: this also converts mp4 videos to a File.

[originally answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52712072/8253662)

Answer (score 1):

The answers here are relevant and help explain how dart and flutter image compression/conversion works.  If you would like a shortcut, there is this package https://pub.dev/packages/network_image_to_byte that makes it really easy.

Answer (score 1):

As http needs Uri this would be helpful:
you should remove the begining serverAddress from your ImageAddress first :
something like this in my case that I have 3001 in my url:

```
    String serverAddress = 'myAddress.com:3001';
    int indexOf3001 = imageAddress.indexOf('3001');
    String trimmedImageAddress= imageAddress.substring(indexOf3001 + 4);
```

then :

```
    var imageUrl = Uri.https(serverAddress, trimmedImageAddress);
    final http.Response responseData = await http.get(imageUrl);
    Uint8List imageBytes = responseData.bodyBytes;
```

this works on device and web too, hope it can help.