# Flutter: Efficient Image filtering

Tags: flutter

So I am using Dart's [image package](https://pub.dev/packages/image) to manipulate an JPG image which was loaded and decoded.
Filtering the image works perfectly fine, however, display the image seems to be somewhat slow.

The idea was to use Flutter's `Image` widget in combination with a `MemoryImage` a la:

```
Image.memory(bytes)
```

`bytes` must be a binary representation of the image, e.g., PNG, JPG etc. and is not compatible with the image library's internal uint32 storage format or a simple bitmap. As a result, one is required to encode the bitmap back to a JPG which is pretty slow.

Is there a more efficient way of doing this?

Comment: look up: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53184821/8240072

Comment: The problem is not loading the image or accessing its bytes. My question is about displaying the image.