# How to get a Uint8List from a Network image by url in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have the network url of image and I need to get Uint8List. How can I convert it?
I check answers in like question, but those ways don't work.
[How to get a Flutter Uint8List from a Network Image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53182480/how-to-get-a-flutter-uint8list-from-a-network-image)

Comment: what does "dont work" mean?

Comment: It means, that code is not actual for the latest version of Flutter. `var load = sunImage.load(val);` Method load requires two required parameters are NetworkImageKey and DecoderCallback

Comment: `final DecoderCallback callback = (Uint8List bytes, {int cacheWidth, int cacheHeight}) {
  print(bytes.length);
  return instantiateImageCodec(bytes, targetWidth: cacheWidth, targetHeight: cacheHeight);
};

ImageProvider provider = AssetImage('images/bg.png');
provider.obtainKey(createLocalImageConfiguration(context)).then((key) {
  provider.load(key, callback);
});` i tested with `AssetImage` but it should work with any `ImageProvider`

Comment: nothing, `provider.load(key, callback)` is called

Comment: And when must be called `print(bytes.length)`?

Comment: when you get the encoded data, tried to run the code i posted (changing only 'images/bg.png'`)?

Comment: Yes I tried, and instead of asset image I did it `ImageProvider provider = CachedNetworkImageProvider("myUrl");`.  After calling method `provider.load(key, callback);` nothing happens.

Comment: i have no idea how you call it and what you mean by `"myUrl"` but i used: `ImageProvider provider = NetworkImage('https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_92x30dp.png')` and it works just fine, it prints `got data: 3831 bytes`

Comment: I used `NetworkImage` instead CachedNetworkImage and I got bytes. I'll try to get image after it

Comment: then call `provider.load(key, callback).addListener(listener)` - i mean add `.addListener(listener)` to the existing code

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works. You can copy your code and add to answer

Comment: feel free to write a self answer ;-)

Comment: Isn't it simpler to use http get like this answer? https://stackoverflow.com/a/58310260/2942294

Comment: @syonip The code looks simpler in that example, but some people can't run that code and they have different errors

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Uint8List yourVar;
final DecoderCallback callback = (Uint8List bytes, {int cacheWidth, int cacheHeight}) {
        yourVar = bytes.buffer.asUint8List();
        return instantiateImageCodec(bytes, targetWidth: cacheWidth, targetHeight: cacheHeight);
      };
ImageProvider provider = NetworkImage(yourImageUrl);
    provider.obtainKey(createLocalImageConfiguration(context)).then((key) {
      provider.load(key, callback);
    });
```

Comment: but you dont have `addListener()` - wasnt your intention to get decoded `ui.Image` object?

Comment: I wanted to get bytes of an image

Comment: but you also said: *"I'll try to get image after it "* - so its not true anymore?

Comment: I mean bytes, because I use bytes for saving my image.

Comment: ok i get it now - but actually wouldnt it be better if you used `http` package [directly](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/networking/fetch-data)?

Answer (score 14):

Try this:

```dart
Uint8List bytes = (await NetworkAssetBundle(Uri.parse(url)).load(url))
    .buffer
    .asUint8List();
```

Comment: Hi there, I'm trying to use your code in a bloc instead of downloading the image with an http get as on web the CORS policy doesn't allow it. and when on web I'm getting an `BlocError:  Unsupported operation: Platform._version`. Any idea why?
Many thanks.

Comment: Hi @Vincenzo , I've tested on mobile not on web but if it's about cors policy you should consider using same domain, allow-origin header or jsonp.

Comment: hi @kaya, I actually solved it yesterday, I indeed had to define core header for my google storage bucket. now I can download them as I was. Many thanks for answering.

Answer (score 3):

this did the trick for me:

```
import 'dart:typed_data';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

//Get the image from the URL and then convert it to Uint8List
Uint8List bytes = (await NetworkAssetBundle(Uri.parse('https://some_image_url.png'))
            .load('https://some_image_url.png'))
            .buffer
            .asUint8List();
```

Answer (score 1):

This works on me (using flutter web) with a library [file_saver](https://pub.dev/packages/file_saver).

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);

Uint8List bytes = await readBytes(uri);
await FileSaver.instance.saveFile(filename, bytes, 'jpg',
    mimeType: MimeType.JPEG); // specify your vars
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same problem in Flutter web, I had to use the [extended_image](https://pub.dev/packages/extended_image) library, and I found inside your example that has a method that allows you to convert an ImageProvider to Bytes.

https://github.com/fluttercandies/extended_image/blob/master/example/lib/pages/simple/image_editor_demo.dart.

```
/// it may be failed, due to Cross-domain
Future<Uint8List> _loadNetwork(ExtendedNetworkImageProvider key) async {
  try {
    final Response response = await HttpClientHelper.get(Uri.parse(key.url),
        headers: key.headers,
        timeLimit: key.timeLimit,
        timeRetry: key.timeRetry,
        retries: key.retries,
        cancelToken: key.cancelToken);
    return response.bodyBytes;
  } on OperationCanceledError catch (_) {
    print('User cancel request ${key.url}.');
    return Future<Uint8List>.error(
        StateError('User cancel request ${key.url}.'));
  } catch (e) {
    return Future<Uint8List>.error(StateError('failed load ${key.url}. \n $e'));
  }
}
```