# Flutter - How to convert an NetworkImage into an ui.Image?

Tags: image, flutter

I need to convert a NetworkImage to an ui.Image. 
I tried to use the given solution from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59926578/6423837) with some adjusts but it isn't working.

Someone can help me?

```
 Uint8List yourVar;
 ui.Image image;
    final DecoderCallback callback =
        (Uint8List bytes, {int cacheWidth, int cacheHeight}) async {
      yourVar = bytes.buffer.asUint8List();
      var codec = await instantiateImageCodec(bytes,
          targetWidth: cacheWidth, targetHeight: cacheHeight);
      var frame = await codec.getNextFrame();
      image = frame.image;
      return image;
    };
    ImageProvider provider = NetworkImage(yourImageUrl);
    provider.obtainKey(createLocalImageConfiguration(context)).then((key) {
      provider.load(key, callback);
    });
```

Comment: why not to use [http](https://pub.dev/packages/http) package directly and `decodeImageFromList` top level function?

Comment: With http i can cache the image? I asked about NetworkImage cause i intend to use CachedNetworkImageProvider.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

first create a field in your class:

```
var cache = MapCache<String, ui.Image>();
```

then to get `ui.Image` you can simply call:

```
var myUri = 'http:// ...';
var img = await cache.get(myUri, ifAbsent: (uri) {
  print('getting not cached image from $uri');
  return http.get(uri).then((resp) => decodeImageFromList(resp.bodyBytes));
});
print('image: $img');
```

of course you should add some http response error handling but this is the base idea...