# Blob URL to Uint8List - Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, blob

I using a package called [flutter_sound](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_sound) to record audio in Web but the result after finish the record is like that

> blob:http://localhost:54779/f1b68f68-8007-4168-abd3-3de5ec8cabbe

how to convert it to a Uint8List in flutter to upload it to anything such as firestore.

Answer (score 0):

Try to read for an answer here: [How to get a Uint8List from a Network image by url in Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59894880/how-to-get-a-uint8list-from-a-network-image-by-url-in-flutter?rq=2)

You have a binary object that you have url to. Just download it  and store it as UIntList.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (kIsWeb) {
  final blobFilePath = html.window.sessionStorage[audioFilePath];
  if (blobFilePath != null) {
    final uri = Uri.parse(blobFilePath);
    final client = http.Client();
    final request = await client.get(uri);
    final bytes = await request.bodyBytes;
    print('response bytes.length: ${bytes.length}');
  }
}
```

`audioFilePath` is the blob url actually, can be found in startPlayer method in `demo.dart` file for example.

Hope this helps.

P.S.
`http` package has been added in `pubspec.yaml` file, `http.Client()` imported from it.