voice recording in flutter web
I am trying to record voice with flutter_sound package in flutter. After stop recording, it returns voice's path as something like this: blob:http://localhost:64911/e9c17898-7698-4fd5-8739-be1d8b53153c.
how can I convert it to Uint8List? I need to upload it to server?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76610310/blob-url-to-uint8list-flutter

import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

Uint8List bytes = (await http.get(Uri.parse("http://localhost:64911/e9c17898-7698-4fd5-8739-be1d8b53153c"))).bodyBytes;

