# How to download image from network and use as an asset image offline in flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, sqflite

I am using [sqlflite](https://pub.dev/packages/sqflite) flutter package to manage a small database for my app, there is a table where I have some urls for few images from the internet , but I need to save them and use the files instead of urls to show this images later. I mean I want to do something like this :

```dart
bool internet
internet ? Image.network('the_url') : Image.assets("path to image in my assets folder")
```

so, is there any way to fetch images from urls and save it to be able to access it later?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can download the image with `NetworkAssetBundle` and convert to Unint8List

```
final ByteData imageData = await NetworkAssetBundle(Uri.parse("YOUR_URL")).load("");
final Uint8List bytes = imageData.buffer.asUint8List();
```

Then you can load it through `Image.memory()` widget

```
Image.memory(bytes);
```

You can store that data in sqflite and retrive when needed

Comment: Seems like not working for Flutter Web (3.0.5), error shows `Unsupported operation: Platform._version`. Any solution that will work on Flutter Web?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the path_provider package to download from internet and save it locally. Then you can load from local asset if available. Otherwise it can download from the internet also.

```
  Future<String?> loadPath() async {
    var dir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    String dirName = widget.url!.substring(87);
    file = File("${dir.path}/$dirName");

    if (file.existsSync() == true && _isDownloadingPDF == false) {
      // debugPrint('file.path returned');
      return file.path;
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried https://pub.dev/packages/cached_network_image?

It seems like this package will fulfil your requirements.

Comment: please be more specific  and provide some code, explaining how this actually converts a network image to Image